# Diagramming a web site

Tags: website-design

How can a web site be diagrammed to show different database elements, web UI elements, and different web pages in relation to each other (all are part of the same web site)?

Essentially I want to be able to show the structure of the site, but not just the web elements  (including the database elements, and other server side elements).

I was wondering if there is a particular way of approaching this with regard to UML, or something similar. Pretty platform agnostic, but with a preference for visio.

Comment: If this question is off topic, please explain why, and if it can be made on topic, advice would be appreciated.

Comment: It really has nothing to do with graphic design. It would be more appropriate at [webmasters](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com).

Comment: It is about showing the structure though, not what the structure  should be.

Comment: What kinds of relations exist, and what are you trying to communicate? Is it something like "for this use case, this server component accesses this data and places it into this page, which shows these UI elements"?

Comment: Something like that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Starting with a site outline.  You can read [Site Diagrams: Mapping an Information Space](http://boxesandarrows.com/view/site_diagrams_mapping_an_information_space), it contains everything you need to know.  A small excerpt:

> A site diagram might initially sound like a site outline. And while not technically a part of the site diagram, a site outline complements the diagram quite well. The site outline presents the website structure in a typical outline format, perfectly mirroring the numbering, levels, and labels in the site diagram. The advantages of site outlines is that they are faster to create and maintain than site diagrams, but their drawbacks include difficulties showing linear page sequences and limits in their ability to mention functionality and other content types, mainly due to the visual clutter the extra text creates.

You can also create diagrams using this online tool:  [Good looking diagrams](http://www.gliffy.com/)

Comment: I see a way to add a database, but is there a way to add tables to the database?

Comment: I guess its not related to GD is it so?

Comment: Not following. I am talking about on the diagram on gliffy.

Comment: I did not used  that deep but I guess you can draw all the things by creating blank document and doing all the steps one by one...In short I have no specific idea about that I am sorry...

Comment: see  this might be this will help though I am not sure : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/918620/are-there-any-online-database-schema-drawing-tools